# PHP Detect uniquie ip for each device for a network ip

Tags: php, ip, user-agent

I need to get a unique ip for each device that visits the web site as the remote_addr give the ip of the network.

Or if there is anything that i can differentiate between any device that visits my site

Comment: No, you can't do that.  I'm behind a NAT.  All you can see is my *external* IP.  You cannot see my *internal* NAT addresses.

Comment: You can use sessions (or even just cookies) to do this, maybe.  Each user that visits your site will have a *different* session id.

Comment: and there is anything else i can do to differentiate between any computer ?

Comment: using java applet, but i think that applet is no more supported by modern browsers, due to security risks

Answer (score 0):

## Welcome to the Internet!

Unfortunately, no, because that's not how IP address work. A device is not required to have a unique IP address, because networks can be interlinked (*i.e. the **internet***). Devices only need identify themselves uniquely within a given subnet (*i.e. to the router/access point they are talking to directly*), which is typically done through a [MAC Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) which is never explicitly broadcasted outside of a local area network. Even if it was (despite not being made available by any standard protocol used on the Internet today) it would still be useless given that it can be faked (*but that's irrelevant to the purposes it is used for in local area network communication - i.e. [ARP](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/Address-Resolution-Protocol-ARP)*). Beyond that point the broadcast IP can and most likely will change.